# CSS Transform Attributes Not Applying to SVG Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, transform

Im currently having an issue where for whatever reason I can't get any Transform CSS attributes to apply to an SVG image inside a div.

Here is the CSS for the code in question:

```
#interior-map-container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.74);
  position: relative;
}

#interior-map {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scale(0.3);
}
```

I've tested replacing the svg file (which is interior-map) with a JPG and still could not get the transform styles to apply. Other styling applies just fine, it's just transform attributes. Any suggestions would be great, thank you.

Comment: Can you share the html portion of your code?

Comment: Here's a resource that may be helpful https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/#aa-scaling

Comment: Are you using nested svg elements in your map? If so, this question might give some hints: [scale a svg element which is inside an other svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093530/scale-a-svg-element-which-is-inside-an-other-svg/71101980#71101980). But please also add a code example.